# How to copy data from one excel file to second excel file using conditions?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have two excel files are `one.xlxs and two.xlxs`. Column names are `id, mail, name, gender, age, name` same on two excel files but they are jumbled in two.xlxs.  Two rows(`id and mail`) have data on both files. I want to copy the data from one.xlxs to two.xlxs. But the column lineup should not be disturb on two.xlxs. The data will be copied based on Two rows(`id and mail`). for example: the data should be copied into the respective columns if id and mail matches on two files. Please find the reference pictures are   one.xlxs, two.xlxs and result_two.xlxs(As required result). I have searched on internet but i did not get any idea.

I am able to copy data from one.xlxs to two.xlxs using below code.
But i don not want to disturb two.xlxs column positions. I want to copy data as shown in the image of two_result.xlxs, If id and mail values matches on both excel files that cell values will be placed on two.xlxs their matched columns. How to do.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_excel('one.xlsx')
df2 = pd.read_excel('two.xlsx')
df = pd.concat([df1])
df.to_excel('two.xlsx', index=False)
```

[image] [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can merge them then rearrange the columns:

```py
cols = df2.columns
result = df2[['id', 'mail']].merge(df1, how='left', on=['id', 'mail']).reindex(columns=cols)

result.to_excel('result.xlsx', index=False)
```

Comment: Its working very well. I am agreeing and accepting your answer. But i forgot one thing to add in the question that is, if any extra columns are in two.xlsx file. Its showing `raise KeyError(f"{not_found} not in index")
KeyError: "['non'] not in index"` error 'non' is a extra column. Before this question closing, Can you please rectify this issue also some times some extra columns also will be there.

Comment: You can use `reindex`. See my edited answer

Comment: But the data will be empty on extra columns After reindex..